How to consider headers a part of time series
I am trying to replicate a financial model in ag grid and use integrated charting. My issue is that I also have distinct categories that I dont have as headers. So they would be the first item in the row. enter image description here.
I tried every iteration of chartDataType for the first item in the ColDef array and the next items in the CodDef (the time series ones). When using integrated charting I want to figure out how to consider each row its own time series, not vertically but horizontally. Attached is an image of a line chart which I dont want. enter image description here

When using createRangeChart you can specify a boolean switchCategorySeries property.
Set this to true, and the rows and columns are transposed with each grid row being a chart series.
This was just introduced in version 31.2.0.
See https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/integrated-charts-api-range-chart/#reference-CreateRangeChartParams-switchCategorySeries for the documentation.

Thanks alot for this, do you mind linking to the docs where it is referenced or providing a small example. I am using react.

Also is there a way to do this on user created range charts? I am only seeing it on application created charts.

I added a link in the original.
User created range charts will have a toggle-switch in the toolpanel

Is there a way to automatically have it checked to true? Playing around with it now

Use the switchCategorySeries option in the createChart method

Sorry but that only works for either the createRangeChart method, I want it by default on any user created chart. Any references?
